# Embedded Jetty 8 with Servlet 3.0 support

Tags: annotations, embedded-jetty, servlet-3.0, jetty-8

How to configure Jetty to work with annotated servlets? The answer from here: [Servlet 3.0 support in embedded Jetty 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463264/servlet-3-0-support-in-embedded-jetty-8-0) by Jeff Miller haven't helped. Without his proposed line (context.setConfigurations..) the web app inside provided war file is starting - I know that because app's contextListner writes to console on apps start. Now if I add the line as suggested by Jeff, the app doesn't start at all.. Is there a way to have servlet annotations working in jetty or should i rewrite servlet annotations back to web.xml?